# How TradingView Pine Script RMA works?

Tags: pine-script, moving-average, indicator

I faced the problem that I wanted to implement the same indicators as in the trading view, but I can't correctly implement the RMA indicator.

If I refer to the documentation, I get the following code:

```
pine_rma(src, length) =>
    alpha = length
    sum = 0.0
    sum := na(sum[1]) ? sma(src, length) : (src + (alpha - 1) * nz(sum[1])) / alpha
```

Everything in it is clear to me, except for the when **na(sum[1])** condition may occur. And do I understand correctly that **nz(sum[1])** is the previous value of **sum**.

When I try to implement it in golang, they write the following code:

```
func RMA(value []float64, period int) float64 {
    var sum float64 

    for i := period - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        sum = (sum * (float64(period) - 1) + value[i]) / float64(period)
    }

    return sum
}
```

And I am having strong discrepancies in the returned data.

I tried to understand what values ​​are obtained in order from the RMA with a period of 3, when the input parameters for it are

**src[0] = 0, src[1] = 0** and **src[2] = 0.12**

and we get that

**rma[0] = 0.06, rma [1] = 0.04** and **rma [2] = 0.03**

and I don't understand where such numbers are taken, because I substitute src in the original formula, we get the most different numbers.

I took the benchmark data from the down array created for RSI from the *FORD MTR CO DEL, 1D, Cboe BZX* chart for September 2, 2020.

Comment: `nz ()` is normally used for processing non-defined areas such as time gaps or start of data. For the implementation, it seems like missing the initial `SMA` call. `for` cycle over the `period` is also questionable

Comment: As per the pinescript [docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_rma), RMA is just the exponentially weighted moving average with alpha = 1 / length. Try [`pandas.Series.ewm`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html) for a reference calculation, but I gave it `period * 4` data points for bootstrapping.